# Deploy fails with "Error: Can't find npm module" in Meteor Galaxy

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, npm, npm-install

I tried to deploy to Meteor Galaxy  and it didn´t work at all, although everything seems to be working on localhost.

At first, my app was uploaded, but than failed to start. At least, the containers start right now, but than my App is crashing. I think it is a systematic fail within my app structure. Perhaps some npm dependencies are missing in package.json or I need to debug some npm installations?

I don´t think that I have understood exactly how npm is working within Meteor, which dependencies I need to have or what I have to import/require to use npm packages correctly. The meteor docs did not help.

Here are my error logs:

```
Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run

 meteor npm install --save bcrypt

in the root directory of your application.
/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
    throw(ex);
    ^

Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor/browser-policy-common'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
 at Object.require (/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:230:17)
 at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:641:18)
 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:234:16)
 at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.browser-policy.js (imports/startup/server/browser-policy.js:1:32)
 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
 at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.index.js (imports/startup/server/index.js:1:66)
 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
 at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js:1:14)
 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
 at /app/bundle/programs/server/app/app.js:3668:1
 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:338:34
 at Array.forEach (native)
 at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

It does not matter which module is missing, it seems to be that Galaxy can´t find any of the used npm modules. Before that try, I had the same error with another npm module. Than I just deleted the Npm.require of that module in my code. Now, I have the same error, just with another module.

I think I missed something during the local usage of npm. I am a complete beginner. Everything worked fine locally and now I can´t bring it online. I am using Windows.

Comment: Could you show your `package.json`?

Comment: Many thanks, I think I know now, where you are going. It was a general issue, because I never used the --save flag when adding npm packages and therefore had no dependencies of them in my `package.json`. I removed `node_modules` and runned `meteor npm install --save` for every npm package and the error had been gone (additionally I removed the browser-policy package for other reasons).  However, now while the app is hosted, I receive errors in the browser console online...Maybe you also know how to solve this? I would appreciate your help. I added an update section in my original post, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue yourself, but I suggest you to close this question and open another one.

Answer (score 0):

It was a general issue, because I never used the `--save` flag when adding npm packages and therefore had no dependencies of them in my `package.json`. I removed node_modules and runned `meteor npm install --save` for every npm package and the error had been gone (additionally I removed the `browser-policy package` for other reasons).